# Get the complete url in managed bean JSF Spring

Tags: facebook-graph-api, servlets, jsf-2

Hi I am doing facebook login feature in my application. Now problem is that, when I logged in from facebook account, I am redirected to my specified redirected url with access token. I need to grab this access token in managed bean. My redirected url is like that :
localhost:8080/XXXXXX/myholiday.xhtml#access_token=AAAGHUgDJZCg0BAG2I8o

I have tried:

```
          HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();


    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();

    System.out.println(url);


    System.out.println( FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("access_token"));


    // Getting request information without the hostname.

    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    System.out.println(uri);
```

Output is the following :
localhost:8080/xxxxxxx/myholiday.xhtml

null

xxxxxxx/myholiday.xhtml

can anyone please help me to grab the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can not* get the access token if it is passed in the hash part of the URL, because the hash part *does not* get transmitted to the server.

You haven’t shown us, how exactly you call the Auth dialog – but it has a parameter `response_type` that can be set to `code` or `token`. `code`should be the default – if you have it set to `token`, change that.

(Or, if your login gets triggered by [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals), set the `Auth Token Parameter` setting in your app settings to `Query String`.)

Then follow the [Server-Side Authentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) from there.